# Can I increase the depth of my deck treads to gain footspace?

Tags: deck, stairs

I have a deck where the contractor is building deck steps. Rise is 7-11/16" and run is currently 10-3/4" with 3/4 inch overhang. If I increase the run to 11-1/4" with a 1-1/4" overhang will I make things better or worse? I'm in my 60s and want a larger space to land my feet going up.

Comment: "will I make things better or worse" will be opinion-based, which is off-topic on this site, and perhaps not answerable, since it is better or worse for whom. "Will it be within code" is more definable, and can be answered by your local code authority, who have the authority to force you to change it to get approval. They may have suggestions on how to make wider steps within code.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your goal of increasing tread depth, this should make things a bit better without creating a hazard.

I don't consider 1¼" overhangs to be problematic. 1½" about the maximum I'd use. Any more and things start to get trippy. 1⅛" is what I consider ideal for most cases.

---

This has been my opinion, and is worth approximately US$0.02.

Answer (score 0):

Codes generally provide minimums for tread length… adding a bit to yours would be fine.

You might also consider adding a tread, thus reducing the rise as you increase the run.